# Save not pulling data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I click on my save button it triggers my Edit Action method, but it doesn't pull any of the data that was marked as editable. which cause it to error out with the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an' object. I'm hoping to have the end result be when I open up my table after clicking edit I can make the changes that I want and then save the data and re-display it to the user.

```
public ActionResult Edit(LansingMileage lansing)
        {

            try
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    LansingMileage update = (from c in db.LansingMileages
                                             where c.RowIndex == lansing.RowIndex
                                             select c).FirstOrDefault();
                    update.TravelDate = lansing.TravelDate;
                    update.ExpMonthYr = lansing.ExpMonthYr;
                    update.TripType = lansing.TripType;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This is my cshtml page

```
<tr id="@item.RowIndex">

                <td>
                    @*<button class="edit-user display-mode">Delete</button>*@
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RowIndex }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "delete-button" })
                    <button class="edit-user display-mode">Edit</button>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "LansingMileage"))
                    {
                        <button class="save-user edit-mode" type="submit" name="Save">Save</button>
                    }

                    <button class="cancel-user edit-mode">Cancel</button>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.ExpMonthYr
                    </span>

                    <label id="ExpMonthYr">
                        <input type="date" id="expenseMonthYr" name="expenseMonthYr" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.TravelDate
                    </span>
                    <label id="TravelDate">
                        <input type="date" id="TravelDateOf" name="TravelDateOf" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-mode">
                        @item.StringTripType
                    </span>
                    <select id="triptype" name="triptype" class="edit-mode">
                        <option value="1"> One Way</option>
                        <option value="2">Round Trip</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <!--Here is where I will create a table to display my data from the above section-->
            </tr>
```

This is my javascript

```
$(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();
            $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function (e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
            });

            $('.save-user').on('.click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');

                var ExpMonthYr = tr.find("#ExpMonthYr").val();
                var TravelDate = tr.find("#TravelDate").val();
                var triptype = tr.find("#triptype").val();

                tr.find("#ExpMonthYr").text(ExpMonthYr);
                tr.find("#TravelDate").text(TravelDate);
                tr.find("#triptype").text(triptype);

                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();

                var LansingMileageModel = {
                    "ExpMonthYr": ExpMonthYr,
                    "TravelDate": TravelDate,
                    "triptype": triptype
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/LansingMileage/Edit',
                    data: JSON.stringify(LansingMileageModel),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

Comment: Please remove the commented-out code from the post.

Comment: In your cshtml page, are you referencing the model LansingMileage for binding?

Comment: I added my Javascript as well to better display what I'm doing, but I have bound this to a model that is updated through the controller as well.

Comment: Please remove the try/catch from your code - it adds nothing of value. The empty catch block is an antipattern - doing so basically says you don't care whether the code works or not.

Comment: @mason I just haven't finished that portion yet, but that isn't what I'm worried about with this application.

Comment: Your `Edit` action method is expecting form data but you're sending JSON data.

Comment: Okay how can I change the data I'm sending to form data? @madreflection

Comment: When you intercept the click, copy the inputs into hidden inputs within the form (use `Html.HiddenFor`) and then call the form's `submit` function.

Comment: @madreflection Would you write that up as an example answer as I'm not following.

Comment: Maybe, as a function of available time.

Comment: @madreflection can you still use html.HiddenFor  when using <input type="date" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199259/discussion-between-madreflection-and-dominik-willaford).